# What does cps do in redux saga?

Tags: redux, redux-saga, cps

It's about 5 months that I work with redux-saga, it's a great and strong middleware library.

I know almost everything in redux-saga, but I couldn't still understand "cps".

Can anyone explain me (with an example) what can be done with "cps"?

I really appreciate if someone takes me out of this confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cps` effect is there to easily handle asynchronous functions that receive a [nodejs style callback](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/errors/what-are-the-error-conventions/) as last parameter.

```
const doSomething = (param1, param2, callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(null, 'done')
  }, 1000)
}

function* saga() {
  const result = yield cps(doSomething, 'foo', 'bar')
  console.log(result) // 'done'
}
```

Documentation: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#cpsfn-args

Comment: So it's being done once the function terminates and callback gets executed?

Comment: @AmirGorji Exactly. It will be done either with a value provided as second param, or if you send an error in the first param of the callback it will throw the error and you can catch it with `try..catch` in the saga.